# Android Design UI Element PSDs

Tags: android, user-interface, psd

About to start on designing an Android 4.0 app, and need to develop mockups for our client.

The images on Android Design (http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) are great, but it'd be awesome if we could get our hands on PSDs of those elements to really build the design out in Photoshop for the client and for our own design sake.

Anyone have their hands on these or know who to contact to get PSDs?

The ASU New Media Innovation Lab would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this awesome PSD available for free download.
http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/android-gui-psd-high-density/

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there any assets which were published with these guidelines.
There are some downloadables for Roboto font

http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html?

There is a download there called Stencils and Sources which I think is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: In general link only answers are discouraged, try to explain how/why your links will help